# Implement python lxml custom resolver

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I am new to xsl transformation and currently trying to convert an special purpose xml macro language over to xslt. I have been able to port over every capability except one which I am look for possible solutions.

Currently it has the line of code below:

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find my_package)/temp/common.xacro"/>
```

It performs the same action as the:

```
<xsl:include href="/home/my_package/temp/common.xslt" />.
```

The issues is the $(find package), basically the parser searches a specific location which returns the full path to the package "/home/my_package" and then includes the file.

I have read that it is not possible to include variables with in the href for the xsl:include, but I have read in a few places stating to use a resolver.

```
<xsl:include href="package:my_package/temp/common.xslt" />.

Python lxml:

import lxml.etree as macro

class PrefixResolver(macro.Resolver):
    def resolve(self, url, pubid, context):
        if url.startswith("package"):
            #some code that populates results_xml
            return self.resolve_filename(result_xml, context)

def main(args):
    honk_parser = macro.XMLParser()
    honk_parser.resolvers.add(PrefixResolver())
    honk_doc = macro.parse(xslt_filepath, honk_parser)
    tran = macro.XSLT(honk_doc)
    f = StringIO.StringIO('<junk></junk>')
    dom = macro.parse(f)
    new_dom = tran(dom)
    print macro.tostring(new_dom, pretty_print=True)
```

I have been unable to get a working solution because:

1) I am not sure if this is even possible

2) If possible not sure exactly what the resolver should be returning